# UIToolbarButton segue to specific view within UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

We're building out an application that starts with a `UIViewController` that includes a `UIToolBar` with `UIToolBarButtonItems`.  The `storyboard` also has a `UITabBarController` with five tabs and scenes.  How do we `segue` to a specific `UITabBarController` scene instead of just landing on the first scene of the `UITabBarController`?  `Storyboard` screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: MemberDetailsViewController* controller = [self.Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerIdentiferInStoryBoard"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

In your tabbarbutton action write this line.

**Objective-c:**

This will select the tab:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: yourtabindex];

**selectedViewController** is used for load the yourtabindex.

self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:yourtabindex];
```

**Swift**

```
var selectedIndex = tabBarController!.selectedIndex
var yourViewControllerObject = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[selectedIndex] as yourViewController
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate using swift?